# "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" with Disqus on Backbone website

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, disqus

I have a website on Backbone.
When I try to execute Disqus code i get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

How can I fix it? Why is this happening?

```
var disqus_shortname = 'mysite';

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function() {
  var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
  dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

console:

```
undefined
embed.js:1 Unsafe attempt to redefine existing module: BASE
embed.js:1 Unsafe attempt to redefine existing module: apps
embed.js:1 Unsafe attempt to redefine existing module: get
...

embed.js:1 Unsafe attempt to redefine existing module: configAdapter
embed.js:1 Unsafe attempt to redefine existing module: removeDisqusLink
embed.js:1 Unsafe attempt to redefine existing module: loadEmbed
embed.js:1 Unsafe attempt to redefine existing module: reset
embed.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

Comment: seems you have not define either **head** or **body** tag in your HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your document is missing both a `head` and a `body` for some reason.

Try this:

```
(function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script');
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
    dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';

    console.log('head', head);
    console.log('body', body);

    (head || body).appendChild(dsq);
}());
```

Then look in the console.

Comment: But still logs "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

Comment: this error from embed.js screenshot - https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9iFg/8t8pomZXd

Comment: Yes we would need more information to solve your problem, this answer was to help you diagnose what is wrong.  Above the error, do you see anything next to "head" or "body"?  What do you see if you write `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` directly there in the console?

Comment: Head and body exists.

Comment: Ok, but do `head` and `body` exist when logged from within that function?

Comment: Have you run that function in the console on a page that has already run that function?  What environment are you working in?

Comment: I have run it in console of chrome. That is the problem?

Comment: Is your code executing in your own page?  It looks like you are `embed`ing it in another environment.  Perhaps your code is not executing where you think it is.  The environment the code is running in does not contain a `body` or `head` element - does it have a DOM at all?  I can't help you more unless you provide a lot more information and source code.

Comment: I'm stupid! Thank you very much, Alex! It does not work from the Chrome console.

Comment: When I deployed it to the code on the server the problem has gone. Thanks again, Alex!

Answer (score 21):

For those just finding this in 2015, in addition to occurring when "head" or "body" is missing, this error will occur when you do not have the following div somewhere in your page:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

Put that div where you want the disqus thread to actually appear.

Comment: This fixed a similar issue for me. I had the "appendChild of null" error and I just realized I  included the disqus script everywhere but didn't have the comments on each page. Now I just wrapped the code in `if($("#disqus_thread").length){ ... }` and I'm fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved like this:

```
// Only if disqus_thread id is defined load the embed script
if (document.getElementById('disqus_thread')) {
    var your_sub_domain = ''; // Here goes your subdomain
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + your_sub_domain + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
}
```

Thx to @boutell and @June for the clue.